# Вывести все значения по ключу в словаре

Tags: python

Имеется словарь `link_id = {'http://water.agrohim-nn.ru/': 3034407704, 'http://agrohim-nn.ru/analiz-kormov.html': 3034537940, ....}`
ключом выступает ссылка , значением id объявления в я.директ. В ключах много дублей, а значения все уникальны.
Так же имеется почищенный от дублей список ссылок по которым выполняется запрос к сайту:

```
links[...]
badlinks = []
    for l in links:
        r = requests.get(l)
        rr = str(r)
        if rr == '<Response [200]>':
            print (rr,l)
        else:
            badlinks.append(l)
```

Если получаем ответ 200 - печатаем ответ сервера и ссылку.
Если ответ сервера отличныq от 200 - вносим ссылку в список badlinks

Далее стоит задача брать ссылку из badlinks и вывести по ней  все id объявлений, которые к этой ссылке относятся. В этом проблема, плиз хелп!

просто проходить циклом по словарю link_id и делать запросы к каждой ссылке не вариант,  т.к. данных бывает очень много.

Comment: В ключах в принципе никак не может быть дублей, ключи в словаре всегда уникальны

Comment: Сделайте лучше значения списками, содержащими все ID объявлений, относящиеся к ним, тогда вывести все связанные ID можно будет вот так: `print(*link_id[badlink], sep='\n')`